# Javascript code editor with intelligence

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ide

Is there any code editor or even IDE, where you can get some compassion in the form of "method" auto-complete suggestions and "jump to definition", for your javascript code that uses a library like d3.js?

Comment: There's a plugin for Sublime Text that provides some snippets and autocompletion: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/D3.js%20Snippets

Comment: thanks but that doesn't help you work with a library, thanks though

Answer (score 3):

I have found that WebStorm does all that.
Need to [follow here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#configure) to set it up to know your external library (e.g. d3.js in my case) so that it can be smart about it. Download the unminified/debug version of your library first so you can supply it in that dialog. Installing WebStorm was quick and a no-brainer.

If you know of other tools that have these capabilities, please post your answer as well...

WebStorm currently doesn't cost all that much and currently comes with a 30 days trial.